# Visual Studio 2010's Solution Explorer is too sensitive

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer

If I click on something (that is click and let go) in the solution explorer and move the mouse too quickly on two quickly or click on something else too soon, Visual Studio interpretes that as a move.  I'm hooked up to Visual Source Safe, so most of the time it asks me if I'm sure. But every once in a while it doesn't, and I have no idea the file has been moved/copied.  As a result I get compiler errors (or worse runtime issues) that are nearly impossible to track down.  Is there a fix to this?  Any suggestions?  It is very annoying.

Comment: I've noticed this a lot too, very annoying. I'd be interested in finding out if there is a setting or something to change. +1

Comment: You've actually seen it move a file when you moved the mouse **without the button held down**?

Comment: I don't believe you'll find an answer here.  I'd suggest o[pening a connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx) for this.

Comment: @Lloyd, yes and it only seems to happen in 2010. 2008 and 2005 as far as I can tell didn't have this problem.

Comment: @Cody, all I know is I am constantly moving files without wanting too.

Comment: @Will, believe it or not.  I did. :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [VSCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf/) extension

They have a "Prevent accidental Drag & Drop in Solution Explorer" feature